# openpyxl conditional formatting set number format

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-formatting, openpyxl

I'm trying to set the number format in a conditional format.  I have found how to set the font, border and fill colors, but I can't set the number format.  The code I currently have is:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font, Border, Side
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule, DifferentialStyle, Rule

wb = load_workbook(filename='Excel_Templates\MyTemplate.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
red_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF0000', end_color='FFFF0000', fill_type='solid')
pink_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF5050', end_color='FFFF5050', fill_type='solid')
light_pink_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF9B99', end_color='FFFF9B99', fill_type='solid')
blue_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0000FF', end_color='FF0000FF', fill_type='solid')
light_blue_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0066FF', end_color='FF0066FF', fill_type='solid')
v_light_blue_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FF9BC2E6', end_color='FF9BC2E6', fill_type='solid')

side = Side(style='thin', color='FF000000')
myBorder = Border(left=side, right=side, bottom=side, top=side)
my_white_font = Font(color='FFFFFFFF', size=12)
my_black_font = Font(size=12)
p='E3'
num = 'E8'
denom = 'E9'
ws['{0}'.format(p)] = '=IF({0}/{1} >= 2, {0}/{1}, IF(AND({0}/{1}>=0, {0}/{1} <2),{0}/{1}-1, 1-{0}/{1}))'.format(
    num, denom)

    ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p),
                              FormulaRule(formula=['{0} < -0.5'.format(p)], fill=red_fill, font=my_black_font))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p),
                              FormulaRule(formula=['AND({0} < -0.25, {0} >=-0.5)'.format(p)], fill=pink_fill,
                                          font=my_black_font))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p),
                              FormulaRule(formula=['AND({0} < 0, {0} >=-0.25)'.format(p)], fill=light_pink_fill,
                                          font=my_black_font))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p),
                              FormulaRule(formula=['AND({0} >=0, {0} < 1)'.format(p)], fill=v_light_blue_fill,
                                          font=my_black_font))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p),
                              FormulaRule(formula=['AND({0} >=1, {0} <= 3)'.format(p)], fill=light_blue_fill,
                                          font=my_white_font))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p),
                              FormulaRule(formula=['{0} > 3'.format(p)], fill=blue_fill,
                                          font=my_white_font))
```

I want to set the format to be percentage with no decimal points for the first 4 formats and I want to set it to "+"0.0"X" for the last two.  I've looked through the source code and can't find a way to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm using Python 3, and Openpyxl 2.3.0 with Excel 2010.

Update 1:

I updated my code using Charlie's suggestions.  I added:

```
dxf = DifferentialStyle(fill=blue_fill, font=my_white_font, numFmt='0.00%')
ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p), Rule(formula=['{0} > 3'.format(p)], dxf=dxf))
```

which gives me the following error message.

```
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\differential.py", line 57, in __init__
self.numFmt = numFmt
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 42, in __set__
raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.differential.NumFmt'>
```

Update 2:

It turns out that the numFmt option in Differential Style requires a class instance of NumFmt, which is defined in openpyxl.style.differential.  I changed my Update 1 code to the following:

```
from openpyxl.styles.differential import NumFmt
dxf = DifferentialStyle(fill=blue_fill, font=my_white_font, numFmt=NumFmt(10, '0.00%'))
r = Rule('expression', formula=['{0} > 3'.format(p)], dxf=dxf)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p), r)
```

Now those work just fine, however, when I call

```
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

I get the following error message

```
    File "C:/TestProj/openpyxl_test.py", line 90, in <module>
    wb.save("test.xlsx")
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 263, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 230, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 213, in save
    self.write_data(archive, as_template=as_template)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 87, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets(archive)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 158, in _write_worksheets
    xml = sheet._write(self.workbook.shared_strings)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 772, in _write
    return write_worksheet(self, shared_strings)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line 223, in write_worksheet
    for cf in cfs:
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line 119, in write_conditional_formatting
    if rule.dxf != DifferentialStyle():
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\hashable.py", line 77, in __ne__
    return not self == other
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\hashable.py", line 73, in __eq__
    return self.key == other.key
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\hashable.py", line 65, in key
    self._key = hash(tuple(fields))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'NumFmt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the source of your issue is a bug in openpyxl. The problem seems to be that the `NumFmt` class is not hashable. I think this might stem from the fact that it is derived from `Serialisable`, rather than `HashableObject`. As such, it's essentially missing the `__hash__` function. I think you can fix this by adding a `__hash__` function to the NumFmt class like so:

```
class NumFmt(Serialisable):

    numFmtId = Integer()
    formatCode = String()

    def __init__(self,
                 numFmtId=None,
                 formatCode=None,
                ):
        self.numFmtId = numFmtId
        self.formatCode = formatCode

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.numFmtId, self.formatCode))
```

With this, I was able to get the following example to work:
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
    from openpyxl.formatting.rule import  DifferentialStyle, Rule
    from openpyxl.styles.differential import NumFmt

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=r'C:\users\vanhamme\Desktop\foobar.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

blue_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0000FF', end_color='FF0000FF', fill_type='solid')

dxf = DifferentialStyle(fill=blue_fill, numFmt=NumFmt(10, '0.00%'))
rule = Rule('expression', formula=['E3 > 3'], dxf=dxf)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('E3', rule)

wb.save(r'C:\users\vanhamme\Desktop\foobar2.xlsx')
```

This is maybe not the most elegant solution. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand the openpyxl class hierarchy well enough to know if there's a shorter, cleaner route.

Comment: I think you may be on right lines. However, we can probably use a Descriptor to allow reading formatting and allow assignment of just strings with a default code number. Serialisation would then take care of the format code lookup / registration. Needless to say this hasn't been raised as an issue before.

Answer (score 1):

Use `openpyxl.formatting.rule.Rule` directly for full control. `FormulaRule` was kept for backwards compatibility only and does not expose all the possibilities but if you look at its source you'll see that you can pass in any instance of a `DifferentialStyle`

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't figure out how to specify the numFmt=NumFmt(numFmtId, formatCode) function.  It's not clear from the code or the documentation what goes in for numFmtId and formatCode.  Are those the values defined in the Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\numbers.py file?  Everything I tried kept crashing.  Also, from looking at the numbers.py file, it appears that it will error on my custom format of "+"0.0"X" because it is not defined.  Also, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.  Sorry.

Comment: Don't make things any harder than they need be: number format is always just a string.

Comment: I'm clearly not understanding.  I added this line to my code:
ws.conditional_formatting.add('{0}'.format(p), DifferentialStyle(fill=blue_fill, font=my_white_font, numFmt='0.00%')) and it gives me this error:
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\differential.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.numFmt = numFmt
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 42, in __set__
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.differential.NumFmt'>

Comment: 1. create the Dxf, 2. create the Rule, 3. assign the rule to range of cells.